# Convert MD5 into String in java

Tags: java, md5

Can anyone know how to convert the **MD5** to **String**. In my case I have saved the password in **MD5** in database. I am trying to retreive the password and display it in string for the editing purpose.

This is what I have done for converting the string into encrypt format:

```
public static String encrypt(String source) {
   String md5 = null;
   try {
         MessageDigest mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); //Encryption algorithm
         mdEnc.update(source.getBytes(), 0, source.length());
         md5 = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest()).toString(16); // Encrypted string
        } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
         return null;
    }
    return md5;
}
```

I don't know how convert the encrypt format into string for editing the password.

Comment: md5 is a one-way algorithm, you can't get plain password back from encrypted one

Comment: Hashing algorithms produce such result that you cannot get back the original input from the result. If you wish such functionality, try using encryption over hashing. (RSA, for example)

Comment: Adding to Ankit: And that one-way trait is the whole reason for storing it as MD5 in the first place.

Comment: so How to I get the plain password for editing it by the admin.Whenever I try to retrieve the password it gives me the encrypted value.

Comment: The admin never EDITS the password on any properly designed system. He merely CHANGES it.

Comment: @AnkitGautam a perfect hashing algorithm is what you say. However, no hashing algorithm is perfect. See the [holes in md5](http://www.scmagazine.com/hackers-find-hole-to-create-rogue-digital-certificates/article/123407/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    String password = "123456";

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(password.getBytes());

    byte byteData[] = md.digest();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++)
        sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

    System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
```

Comment: The above code convert the string into hex format and my question is how to revert back to string.

Comment: MD% it's one-way algorithm, you cannot convert md5 hex string back to original string.

Comment: It may be useful to add "UTF-8" as argument on getBytes as it may generate a wrong hash when using latin characters, for example.

Comment: @vchyzhevskyi this is the opposite of what was asked for

Answer (score 5):

MD5 is single side hash function. So you cannot decode it. This is why on many web sites you have options "retrieve password" by creating new one.

[More about MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Answer (score 0):

Code for convert String to MD5

```
private static String convertToMd5(final String md5) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuffer sb=null;
        try {
            final java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            final byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (final java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: precisely the opposite of what was asked for!

Answer (score -3):

I think that is the most elegant way to do that:

```
public String getMD5(String data) {
        String result = null;
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(data.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            result = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%032x", new BigInteger(1, md.digest()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return result;
}
```

`

Comment: the opposite of what was asked for!