# Saving username & password in desktop app

Tags: java, swing, security, cookies, passwords

I am making one frame which has two text field one for username & other for password,and one button to login.

Now I want to store my login information for a specified period of time , so that next time   when user open my frame he'll be able to retrieve his login information. I know this is possible through cookies, **but** I need to know how to apply this concept  in my frame.

My application is a windows based application, no link to browser.

How to achieve this feature?

Comment: `frame`, `applets`...which is it?  Are you running the code via a HTML page or is it stand alone?

Comment: @MadProgrammer my application is a stand alone application

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry for this, i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @MadProgrammer is there any solution for this standalone application

Comment: If the application is stand alone application, what does applet have to do with it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I suspect only because the OP thought the concept of a web-app. storing passwords might help explain what they want to do with a desktop app.  The choice of the word/tag `applet` was an unwise addition..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm to old for this type of confusion.  If I wanted that, I'd go to work :P

Answer (score 2):

You can client information to the system in any number of ways...

### You could

Use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html), which allow you to specify key/name pairs of information, which can loaded and saved to a file.

### You could

Use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) which is simluar to the `Properties` API, except you get the added benifit of internal persistence (you don't need to read/write the files), groupings (you can have a `key` specified multiple times, so long as it's in different groups)

As a side note.  You shouldn't be storing passwords in any manner that they might be retrieved.  Instead you should store using something like a MD5 hash and compare hashs.  See [Convert MD5 into String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665360/convert-md5-into-string-in-java) for more details...

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use temporary file to write the user detail. 
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");
The next time the user comes, you can read the data from that temp file. 
Additionally you can make the temp file hidden for more data security.

It seems the temp file name is appended by a random number so it will be better to create the temp file your self.

This code snippet might help you.

```
try {
        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        File tempFile = new File(new File(tempDir), "userDetail.tmp");
        if(tempFile.exists()){//This is subsequent login 
            //Write your code to read file and 
            //your application logic
        }else{ //This is first login 
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            //Write your logic to write data to the file 
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can refactor the code to suit your design.

Comment: how can i read data from temp file? i mean when user comes next time.

Comment: Check the edited content